# Is there any suggestion while using ajax to get post data only token value is coming in laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I am a new user, facing a serious problem while trying to get serialize data in ajax calling through a view opening in modal. Every time except token value i don't get any form data.

> Array (
>       [_token] => xSdktw7zYnVAbdFmKWK3bJbBg0bmAn8icXw4AHYN
>       [email] => 
>       [password] =>  )

### Route

> Route::post('/login-check',
>   'Frontend\HomeController@loginCheck')->name('frontend.loginCheckAjax');

```
function login_submit_action(){
              $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
              }
             });
            var requestUrl         = "{{route('frontend.loginCheckAjax')}}";
            $.ajax({
                url: requestUrl,                
                method: "POST",
                //data:$(this).serialize(),
                data: $("#login_form").serialize(), 
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend:function(){
                    //$("#submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
                    //$("#submit").val('Searching.....')
                },
                success:function(data){

                }
            });
        }
```

Can anybody help me to find out the problem. I am using 5.8 version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can pass Array as `data` to `jQuery.ajax()`, like:

```
data:{email:$('#email_input'),password:$('#password_input')}, ...
```

See also
https://hdtuto.com/article/jquery-ajax-post-request-example-in-laravel-57